# MySQL: update rows based on count condition

Tags: mysql

I need to run query, to check the length of question's text in DB and update its class:

questions table (structure)

```
id     text         class
1      What...?       B
2      how..?         B
3      What..?        B
4      where...?      B
5      when...?       B
```

if the question length less than 100 char, set class = A

thanks,

Comment: `....WHERE CHAR_LENGTH<100`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the mysql CHAR_LENGTH() function to determine the length of the value in the text column.

```
UPDATE questions
SET class = 'A'
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(`text`) < 100
```